# Pass multidimensional array from ajax to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I have tried to post json data from AngularJs `$http` post to an ASP.NET MVC controller. Here is the json data example :

```
     var postdata = {
        Email: "test1@mail.com",
        selectedanswer: {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 1}                       
    };
```

AngularJs code:

```
    $http({
        url: "/page/PostFileWithData",
        headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        },
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(postdata)    
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function (data) {
        console.log('fail');
    });
```

Controller:

```
    public JsonResult PostFileWithData(UserModel userdata)
    { 
        UserModel udata = new UserModel {
            Email = userdata.Email  
            selectedanswer = userdata.selectedanswer
        };

        return Json(udata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My model:

```
    public class UserModel {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string selectedanswer { get; set; }
    }
```

Now the problem is that I am getting `email` field ok in console.log but `selectedanswer` is `null`

Like this

```
    { Email: "test1@gmail.com", selectedanswer: null }
```

Comment: selectedanswer is a `string`. So send like `selectedanswer: "{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 1}"`. While that might fix your current issue. You should consider using a more appropriate type (some collection with name and value properties) instead of using a string

Comment: But how can i parse this string to json like
{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 1}

Comment: You should not use string. Use a type which represents the data.  See the answer i posted.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are passing a Key-Value object from Ajax, change your model to

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int,int> selectedanswer { get; set; }
}
```

Or alternately, send `selectedanswer` in string such as below:

```
var postdata = {
    Email: "test1@mail.com",
    selectedanswer: "{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 1}"
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Model binding is not working for `selectedanswer` property because it is declared as `string` type and you are not sending a string value from your client side code. It will work fine if you send a string value

```
var postdata = {
                  Email: "test1@mail.com",
                  selectedanswer: "{ 0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 1 }"
               };
```

While this might fix your model binding issue, this is not a clean solution to your problem. Now in your action method, you need to parse this string and extract items from that. **There is another clean way to do it**.

Looks like you want to send a list of answers and it's question id/index. Create a view model representing that strucutre and use a collection of that in your UserModel class.

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> SelectedAnswers { set; get; }
}
public class Answer
{
    public int QuestionId { set; get; }
    public int AnswerId { set; get; }
}
```

Now send an array of items, each with a `QuestionId` and `AnswerId` property values.

```
var postdata = {  Email: "test1@mail.com",
                  SelectedAnswers : [
                                       { QuestionId:0, AnswerId:3 },
                                       { QuestionId:1, AnswerId:2 },
                                       { QuestionId:2, AnswerId:0 },
                                       { QuestionId:3, AnswerId:3 },
                                       { QuestionId: 4, AnswerId:1}
                                    ] };
// to do  : send postdata
```

Comment: Thanks @Shyju for you help, now i wanted to create this type of json from and array through loop here is code 
var jsonArr = [];
for (j = 0; j, vm.selectedanser.length; j++) {
                jsonArr.push({
                    QuestionId: vm.selectedanser[j],
                    AnswerId: vm.selectedanser[j]
                });
            }

but this not give this type of json you mentioned, can you please help?

Comment: What is in your array. Can you add the sample data in your array ? what is `vm.selectedanser` and where is it declared and what is inside it.